# Run time exception in the code

Tags: android

I have this code to create a parallax scrolling effect,i could not found any errors in this code but when i run the app it crashes and it is shown that a Run time exception in the code,i did not understand what the problem is.Can anybody help??

Here is my MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private int lastTop = 0;
ImageView image;
ListView listView;

ArrayAdapter adapter;
ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<>();

public void parallax(final View v) {
    final Rect r = new Rect();
    v.getLocalVisibleRect(r);

    if (lastTop != r.top) {
        lastTop = r.top;
        v.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                v.setY((float) (r.top / 2.0));
            }
        });
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    items.add("List Item 1");
    items.add("List Item 2");
    items.add("List Item 3");
    items.add("List Item 4");
    items.add("List Item 5");
    items.add("List Item 6");
    items.add("List Item 7");
    items.add("List Item 8");
    items.add("List Item 9");
    items.add("List Item 10");
    items.add("List Item 11");
    items.add("List Item 12");
    items.add("List Item 13");
    items.add("List Item 14");
    items.add("List Item 15");
    items.add("List Item 16");
    items.add("List Item 17");
    items.add("List Item 18");
    items.add("List Item 19");
    items.add("List Item 20");

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header, null, false);
    image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
    listView.addHeaderView(view);
    listView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            parallax(image);
        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            parallax(image);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Here is my logcat

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{in.zoid.parallaxtutorial/in.zoid.parallaxtutorial.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot add header view to list -- setAdapter has already been called.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot add header view to list -- setAdapter has already been called.
        at android.widget.ListView.addHeaderView(ListView.java:261)
        at android.widget.ListView.addHeaderView(ListView.java:290)
        at in.zoid.parallaxtutorial.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:70)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apply this change your problem solve ::

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private int lastTop = 0;
    ImageView image;
    ListView listView;

    ArrayAdapter adapter;
    ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<>();

    public void parallax(final View v) {
        final Rect r = new Rect();
        v.getLocalVisibleRect(r);

        if (lastTop != r.top) {
            lastTop = r.top;
            v.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    v.setY((float) (r.top / 2.0));
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        items.add("List Item 1");
        items.add("List Item 2");
        items.add("List Item 3");
        items.add("List Item 4");
        items.add("List Item 5");
        items.add("List Item 6");
        items.add("List Item 7");
        items.add("List Item 8");
        items.add("List Item 9");
        items.add("List Item 10");
        items.add("List Item 11");
        items.add("List Item 12");
        items.add("List Item 13");
        items.add("List Item 14");
        items.add("List Item 15");
        items.add("List Item 16");
        items.add("List Item 17");
        items.add("List Item 18");
        items.add("List Item 19");
        items.add("List Item 20");

        View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header, null, false);
        image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
        listView.addHeaderView(view);

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        listView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
                parallax(image);
            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                parallax(image);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Hai Hiren Vaghela It's working,Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you have getting illegalstate because you first assign adapter and then assign header. just reverse this things first assign header and then assign adapter your problem was solved.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private int lastTop = 0;
ImageView image;
ListView listView;

ArrayAdapter adapter;
ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<>();

public void parallax(final View v) {
    final Rect r = new Rect();
    v.getLocalVisibleRect(r);

    if (lastTop != r.top) {
        lastTop = r.top;
        v.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                v.setY((float) (r.top / 2.0));
            }
        });
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    items.add("List Item 1");
    items.add("List Item 2");
    items.add("List Item 3");
    items.add("List Item 4");
    items.add("List Item 5");
    items.add("List Item 6");
    items.add("List Item 7");
    items.add("List Item 8");
    items.add("List Item 9");
    items.add("List Item 10");
    items.add("List Item 11");
    items.add("List Item 12");
    items.add("List Item 13");
    items.add("List Item 14");
    items.add("List Item 15");
    items.add("List Item 16");
    items.add("List Item 17");
    items.add("List Item 18");
    items.add("List Item 19");
    items.add("List Item 20");

    View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header, null, false);
    image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
    listView.addHeaderView(view);

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    listView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            parallax(image);
        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            parallax(image);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I have no reputation so I can only write my words in the answer..
I think you should define a listview class to extends listview, and init the headview in it. like the code below .

```
public FriendCircleList(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    initHeadView(context);
}

private void initHeadView(Context context) {
    headView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.header, null);
    addHeaderView(headView);
    circle = (ImageView) headView.findViewById(R.id.circleprogress);
    headView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(
            new OnPreDrawListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onPreDraw() {
                    if (headView.getMeasuredHeight() > 0) {
                        headViewHeight = headView.getMeasuredHeight();
                        headView.getViewTreeObserver()
                                .removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
    setOnScrollListener(this);
    currentScrollState = OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE;
    currentState = LoadState.LOADSTATE_IDLE;
    firstVisibleItem = 0;
    CircleMarginTop = 76;
    setSelector(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    setItemsCanFocus(true);
}
```

Alse,I think write addheadview() before setadpter() maybe work.
Hope it can help you.